# How to correctly import pixi-sound (PIXI JS)

Tags: javascript, html, import, pixi.js

this might be a dumb question but how do you properly import pixi-sound?

My issue is:

```
import * as PIXI from "pixi.js";
import PIXI_SOUND from "pixi-sound";

const EFFECT_SOUNDS = [...list of music]

for (let name in EFFECT_SOUNDS) {
   PIXI.Loader.shared.add(name, EFFECT_SOUNDS[name]);
}

... more logic

PIXI.Loader.shared.load(function(loader, resources) {
  if (resources[sound]) {

    // this is where the issue is
    resources[sound].sound.play();
    resources[sound].sound.speed= 0.5;
  }
});
```

on the code above `resources[sound].sound.play` and other properties like `exist`, `speed`, `stop`, etc. don't exist.

I tried changing the code to:

```
import * as PIXI_SOUND from "pixi-sound";
```

but this doesn't work.

I also tried `PIXI_SOUND.Loader` but this will throw an error.

Comment: What do you use to bundle your code? It's probably an issue with bundler configuration (eg. missing plugin for handling cjs/esm modules).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this works for me

```
import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js';
window.PIXI = PIXI; // this seems optional
import 'pixi-sound';
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're using [@inlet/react-pixi](https://github.com/inlet/react-pixi), you can import like this

```
import { Container, withPixiApp } from '@inlet/react-pixi';
import { default as PIXI_SOUND } from 'pixi-sound';


PIXI_SOUND.add(key, {
    url: url,
    preload: true,
    loaded: (err, sound) => {
        if (err) {
            console.warn(`load sound ${key} - ${url} error: ${err}`)
        } else {
            console.log(`loaded sound ${key} - ${url}: ${sound.duration} seconds`)
        }
    }
})
```